# Binding Error - Socket programming C

Tags: c, sockets, codeblocks

I am trying to Bind a local socket and it is giving me the error. Not sure where the problem is. Any help?

```
int result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsadata);
    if(result != NO_ERROR)
    {
      printf("\nThere is a problem at WSAStartup");
    }
    else{
        printf("\nWSAStartup was ok");
    }
    list_sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(list_sock == -1)
    {
        printf("\n Socket not created %d\n", list_sock);
    }
    else
    {
    printf("\nSocket was created Succesfully");
    }
HOSTENT *thishost;
char *ip;
u_short port;
port = 55555;
thishost = gethostbyname("localhost");
printf("\n");
printf("\nHost name is:%s ",thishost->h_name);
ip = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)*thishost->h_addr_list);
printf("\nip address is %s\n ", ip);
printf("Address type is:%i",thishost->h_addrtype);
service.sin_family = AF_INET;
service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
service.sin_port = htons(port);
if(bind(list_sock,(SOCKADDR *)&service,sizeof(service))==SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("Error during bind");
}
else
{
        printf("All done");
    }
```

It creates socket and I could display IP address, Name etc. But when binding happens it gives me the error.

Regards,
S

Comment: When bind is failing, check the `errno` and post here

Comment: Please indent your code ...

Comment: strerror(errno) gives me 'no error' but the conditions during bind fails. if(bind(list_sock,(SOCKADDR *)&service,sizeof(service))== SOCKET_ERROR)

Answer (score 0):

If it happens when your run the programm the second time, check SO_REUSE_ADDRESS.

Comment: This happens even before first time it runs successfully. if(bind(list_sock,(SOCKADDR *)&service,sizeof(service))== SOCKET_ERROR) failes but there is no error.